# Proper use of FULLTEXT index for a column storing unique hash value

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, full-text-search

We have an InnoDB table called `user`, where we have a column called `token` (varchar(128)) where a unique md5-like value that represents whether a user is authenticated or not, is stored. This column can be filled or empty/NULL, depending on whether the user has authenticated yet or not.

Whenever an API is being called to make a change to other data, we always check whether the token sent with the API is valid or not. The query would be something like:

```
select * 
from `user` 
where token ='96e1e3c72ce665bc7aeb93a357801fa3296e500b1aed8016e5342e744990cd0094c98857ae5f4b0a73cc6dfebd11a8491a5ba8448e6ddff8a631eb8213c254d0'
```

As you can imagine, this query runs into seconds, because it is a query on a varchar field. Now I'm trying to fix the query speed.

I tried adding a FULLTEXT on the `token` field, but it won't help in the `=` query. So I'm trying to use `MATCH() AGAINST()` query as follows:

```
select * 
from `user` 
where MATCH(token) AGAINST('96e1e3c72ce665bc7aeb93a357801fa3296e500b1aed8016e5342e744990cd0094c98857ae5f4b0a73cc6dfebd11a8491a5ba8448e6ddff8a631eb8213c254d0')
```

But this query **does not return any result**. When I check use `EXPLAIN`, I get:

```
id   1
select_type  SIMPLE
table    user
type fulltext
possible_keys    token
key  token
key_len  0
ref  NULL
rows 1
Extra    Using where
```

Here, the `key_len` being 0, and `rows` saying 1, even though no results were returned, are suspicious to me.

Now I'm thinking even FULLTEXT isn't the solution - it doesn't seem to be working for completely unique values with no common words - not usual text.

Can you help me understand:

1. Why `FULLTEXT` index with `MATCH() AGAINST()` is not bringing any results?
2. What is the best way to index the `token` field and reduce query time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I "can't imagine".  That is, unless you did not have `INDEX(token)`, which is the index that would fast.  Don't use `FULLTEXT` in this situation.

To discuss further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT` for the case of `token = '...'`.

Comment: Hey Rick, simply adding the index(token) did the trick, it looks like - I'll report back later if it hasn't. I'm not great at DBA, and I seem to have missed the obvious here - my impression was that index is for integer fields, and FULLTEXT is the only way to index varchar fields. Thank you kind sir for the guidance!

Comment: `INDEXing` a string column is useful when testing for `=` (in this case) or `BETWEEN` or certain other things.  `FULLTEXT` is when you need to search for _words_ within lengthy text.